# How to share a build for testing?

Tags: android, google-play

I sent the build for testing all the time in this way:

- I build the `app-debug.apk` and send it to all testers by mail
- I send the release apk for internal testing in Google Play.

I tried to upload the debug build to internal testing, but after the release builds it does not allow uploading.

I need to send the debug build to testers, because there is a library for collecting information about requests to the server, or crash logs, etc.

Question:
How can I share a debug build with testers via the Play Console?
And in general, how do you organize all this?
Heard about `CI` and `CD`, but so far my knowledge is not enough for this

Answer (score 0):

When you have different build variants configured to your app, you can use Firebase App Distribution to release version for the testers.

You can automate the proccess by adding a CI/CD pipeline to your environment, or generate apk and add it manually on firebase console.

Here is the Firebase docs for more information:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-console